# Fastest solution to READ on a big simple table of ids (not relational)

Tags: linux, database

We are in the adtech and we need to find the faster solution (and cheapest in CPU/RAM consumption) to read/write (to tens or even hundreds K IOPS) in a very simple matching table of ids like this :

Also we have a doubt on the table schema :

One line per partner

| internal_id (uuid v4) | partner_id (int) | external_id (TEXT, no control on the length) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 923a01d3-c480-4a80-92f1-4e11dfba6ed3 | 24 | XzaV1lVbLoEAAFJkOQkAAAC5&1111 |
| 923a01d3-c480-4a80-92f1-4e11dfba6ed3 | 35 | 4420763609654968920 |
| 04643add-bc2b-4ade-be71-c1a2ad3d4a41 | 24 | X-hgv2QiDJM4LUrlMLuTtwAA&1114 |
| 04643add-bc2b-4ade-be71-c1a2ad3d4a41 | 35 | 244500741791779031 |
| ... | ... | ... |

or

One column per partner

| internal_id (uuid v4) | partner_24 (TEXT, no control on the length) | partner_35 (TEXT, no control on the length) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 923a01d3-c480-4a80-92f1-4e11dfba6ed3 | XzaV1lVbLoEAAFJkOQkAAAC5&1111 | 4420763609654968920 |
| 4c1aeb2a-0773-4c7e-a025-e3c10c662358 | X-hgv2QiDJM4LUrlMLuTtwAA&1114 | 244500741791779031 |
| ... | ... | ... |

The size is very large (billions of internal_id), which is only getting bigger every day.

We don't need 100% data accuracy, we only search speed on the read, writes can be asynchronous or with a small latency.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Redis or memcached? An in-memory hashmap might be faster but it will harder to implement for distributed lookups

Comment: Thx for the reply but the problem that we have multiple front servers, so we have to save in a common database and filling the Redis database would take too much time and resources (we tried python pipelines, but too much time and resources)

If we have a new user entering the system, it will have to go through a message queue to fill the DB and then push it to the other frontends. On a very large volume we'll have too much latency and therefore a gap will be created when we've already captured the user's ID.

We really need to write and read ton he fly.

Comment: I was more thinking in terms of a single backend Redis server (or a Redis cluster for sharding the data) accepting requests from all the front end servers. With enough memory on that server you can keep the whole dataset in-memory and then network latency will be  the major slowdown